# How do I create liferay iframe from jsp

Tags: java, javascript, iframe, liferay, portlet

Here is a scenario. I am working on a small project and in this, I will be forming a URL based on some condition checks. When the final URL is ready ( in JSP), **I have to invoke the liferay iframe** and pass this URL to it so that as the JSP is loaded. It should load the newly created liferay iframe with the URL which I have formed. How to do this in the flow ? Is there any means through which liferay iframe can be created ? (Something from liferay taglib)

Thanks

-Aj

Comment: How are you building the URL? Is it in js?

Comment: Yes. In JS. Fro, the onload function of this JS, I am trying to create an iframe with the URL formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Did something like this.

```
<script>
function show(which) {
var hide = new Array();
hide = document.getElementsByName(which);
for (i=0; i<hide.length; i++) {
hide[i].style.display = 'inline';
}
}
function hide(which) {
var hide = new Array();
hide = document.getElementsByName(which);
for (i=0; i<hide.length; i++) {
hide[i].style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
iframe { display: none; }
</style>
<b>Google</b>
<input type="button" value="Show" onclick="show('iframe');">
<input type="button" value="Hide" onclick="hide('iframe');">
<iframe src='http://www.google.com' width='100%' height='100%' scrolling='yes'       name='iframe'></iframe>
```

Now I can use the show and hide, as I need and use it.

These buttons can be used to maximize and minimize the iframe based on the need and more than 1 iframe can be used in a page too.